# Open file in TagLib with Unicode chars in filename

Tags: c++, string, unicode, taglib

I am quite new to the C++ 'area' so I hope this will not be just another silly 'C++ strings' question.

Here is my problem. I want to integrate [TagLib](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html) (1.5, 1.6 as soon as I manage to build it for Windows) into an existing Windows MFC VS2005 project. I need it to read audio files metadata (not write).

The problem is that the program stores the input file names using CString(), and it has the Unicode option turned on (so the default chars are "wchar_t"). The reason for this (I think, the project was started by someone else) is that some of the 'input' file names could contain Unicode charaters (for example, Japanse or Arabic characters).

For example, the file path is something like "d:\docs\audio_test\stragecharڝhere.mp3", but I get it with:

```
CString fpath = tmpFile->GetFilePath();
```

Now.. if I try to do:

```
TagLib::FileRef f(fpath.GetBuffer(0));
fpath.ReleaseBuffer();
```

I get something like:

> unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public:
>   __thiscall TagLib::FileName::FileName(wchar_t
>   const *)"

If I try something like:

```
TagLib::FileRef f(reinterpret_cast<char*>(fpath.GetBuffer(0)));
fpath.ReleaseBuffer();
```

I get rid of the compilation errors, but "f" is an invalid pointer/object.. and when I try reading a tag, I receive an assert failed.

So, can anyone give me some pointers on how should I pass that CString, in it's Unicode form, to the [TagLib](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html) ?

Update: [TagLib address: http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html)

Thank you,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed something essential when I first read your post, so here is another, new and improved answer:

The error comes from the linker, not the compiler. It thus seems that TagLib::FileName *does* have a ctor taking `wchar_t const*`, but the problem is that you don't link with the library implementing it, or link with a version of the library that does not include it.

IIUC, this library comes from the Linux world (where file names are expressed as `char` arrays), and was later ported to Windows (where file names are expressed as `wchar_t` arrays). The FileName ctor taking a `wchar_t` array is thus probably conditionally compiled on Windows (i.e., inside `#ifdef _WIN32` or something similar), and the library you are linking with (if you are linking the library) was not compiled with the same preprocessor defines.

Comment: Indeed, the library was ported from *nix to windows. And, indeed, it uses some #ifdef to 'select' the data types depending on the platform.

At some point, I will have to compile it myself for windows (the lastest version), as now I was using the precompiled 1.5 MSVC version.

I will try again to use it the - for now, the priorities have changed for the project :)

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that the problem is caused by the issue described [here](http://mail.kde.org/pipermail/taglib-devel/2009-October/001259.html). Basically MSVC has an option to treat the `wchar_t` type differently, which causes the compiled library is not binary compatible with an application compiled without that option. Unfortunately the `CMakeLists.txt` build file enables the `/Zc:wchar_t-` option by default. I'd try to edit the file, remove the option and re-compile TagLib. Ideally version 1.6, as it contains a lot of bug fixes.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the info. Indeed, I will have to compile version 1.6 for windows, because I'm interested specifically in the mp4 tag support (which was added in 1.6). For the moment I was just testing out 1.5 - the binary version compiled (with/for MSVC).

Thank you

Comment: This answer popped up #1 on google when I had the exact same problem.  Killing the /Zc:wchar_t- was exactly what I needed.  Thanks!