# Link failures building TagPy on Windows

Tags: python, windows, taglib, boost-python

I'm a hapless Linux coder trying to get one of my projects working in Windows 7, which involves building TagPy. I'm using MSVC2008 and Python 2.7.1 (x86 version).

I have successfully installed CMake and built TagLib, and installed the Boost headers and Boost.Python binary from the BoostPro installer. I have set the boost and taglib lib dirs, include dirs and lib names, plus the boost compiler, in configure.py.

My %path%, %lib% and %libpath% have the directories for MSVC etc added, as set by the batch script provided by VC.

I get the following errors on link:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /DLL /nologo
/INCREMENTAL:NO "/LIBPATH:C:/Program Files (x86)/taglib/lib" "/LIBPATH:C:\Progra
m Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_46_1\lib" /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Pyth
on27\PCbuild tagd.lib boost_python-vc90-mt-1_46_1.lib /EXPORT:init_tagpy build\t
emp.win32-2.7\Release\src/wrapper/basics.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/wr
apper/id3.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/wrapper/rest.obj /OUT:build\lib.w
in32-2.7\_tagpy.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/wrapper\_tagpy.lib
/MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/wrapper\_tagpy.pyd.manifest

   Creating library build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/wrapper\_tagpy.lib and obje
ct build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/wrapper\_tagpy.exp

basics.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) pu
blic: __thiscall TagLib::String::String(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct s
td::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &,enum TagLib::St
ring::Type)" (__imp_??0String@TagLib@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@
std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@W4Type@01@@Z) referenced in function "public: stati
c void __cdecl boost::python::converter::implicit<class std::basic_string<wchar_
t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >,class TagLib:
:String>::construct(struct _object *,struct boost::python::converter::rvalue_fro
m_python_stage1_data *)" (?construct@?$implicit@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits
@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@VString@TagLib@@@converter@python@boost@@SAXPAU
_object@@PAUrvalue_from_python_stage1_data@234@@Z)

build\lib.win32-2.7\_tagpy.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

What am I missing?

(Note: I previously had Boost-related exceptions in the unresolved externals as well, but passing /EHsc as a compiler flag fixed that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520986/open-file-in-taglib-with-unicode-chars-in-filename/1526606#1526606), I think it's the same problem. The `/Zc:wchar_t-` flag will go away with the next TagLib release, but for now it's enabled in the default `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's correct. Removing that flag from CMakeLists.txt built successfully. A bit of screwing around with the %PATH% later and lo and behold, TagPy works!